# Multiple Linear Regression, Correlation Coefficients

Tags: statistics, regression, linear-regression

Show that the value of ry_hat,y  = ( ry,x1  + ry,x2 +…+ ry,xp)^1/2 if the predictors are pair-wise uncorrelated and rx,y represents the correlation coefficient of x and y. 
y_hat is the collection of estimated y values of the dataset.

Comment: Are you sure it is not the sum of squares of ry,xk?

Comment: @Maffred yes I'm sure it's not squares